# error DNS_ERROR_ZONE_LOCKED in windows server 2022

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2022

I just installed a new DNS server on Windows server 2022 and the problem arises when I try to create a secondary zone on the DNS server. It seems to create the zone fine but then it does not load the zone data.
When I perform the operation "Transfer from master" I get the error "The zone is blocked to transfer or update the zone".

Performing the operation from the command line:
dnscmd /zonerefresh dns_secondary_zone.es
I get the following error:
"Error in command:  DNS_ERROR_ZONE_LOCKED 9607 0x2587"

The secondary zone is created to load data from a master server external to my organization. They confirm to me that there is no blocking and that the master DNS is working with other clients.

Also add that this server was just created from a new migration from a Windows Server 2016 domain controller and the AD, DHCD and DNS roles have been passed over.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the significant properties of the 'Primary' zone?

Comment: The secondary zone is created to load data from a master server external to my organization. They confirm to me that there is no blocking and that the master DNS is working with other clients.

Comment: That doesn't provide any information about the zone. What is the platform? Bind? What version? How many records?